# Pythonの「rstrip」の意味と働きについて教えてください。

Tags: python

◆ Pythonの標準入力のinput()文についての質問です。◆
例文：

```
import random

line = input().rstrip().split(",")
list = ['大吉', '中吉', '吉', '凶']
num = len(list)
print(list)
print(list[random.randrange(num)]
```

■入力した値：大吉、中吉、吉、凶

◆上の例文の3行目のrstrip()について、その意味と働きを教えてください。
　　あと、その後のsplit(",")についても教えてもらえますか。

Answer (score 2):

回答としては、これらになります。
標準入力(だいたいキーボード)から入力した文字列に、それぞれの処理を適用しているものです。

[input([prompt])](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#input)

> 引数 prompt が存在すれば、それが末尾の改行を除いて標準出力に書き出されます。次に、この関数は入力から 1 行を読み込み、文字列に変換して (末尾の改行を除いて) 返します。 EOF が読み込まれたとき、 EOFError が送出されます。例:
>
> ```
> >>> s = input('--> ')  
> --> Monty Python's Flying Circus
> >>> s  
> "Monty Python's Flying Circus"
> ```

[str.rstrip([chars])](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.rstrip)

> 文字列の末尾部分を除去したコピーを返します。引数 chars は除去される文字集合を指定する文字列です。 chars が省略されるか None の場合、空白文字が除去されます。 chars 文字列は接尾語ではなく、そこに含まれる文字の組み合わせ全てがはぎ取られます:
>
> ```
> >>> '   spacious   '.rstrip()
> '   spacious'
> >>> 'mississippi'.rstrip('ipz')
> 'mississ'
> ```

[str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.split)

> 文字列を sep をデリミタ文字列として区切った単語のリストを返します。maxsplit が与えられていれば、最大で maxsplit 回分割されます (つまり、リストは最大 maxsplit+1 要素になります)。 maxsplit が与えられないか -1 なら、分割の回数に制限はありません (可能なだけ分割されます)。
>
> sep が与えられた場合、連続した区切り文字はまとめられず、空の文字列を区切っていると判断されます(例えば '1,,2'.split(',') は ['1', '', '2'] を返します)。引数 sep は複数の文字にもできます (例えば '1<>2<>3'.split('<>') は ['1', '2', '3'] を返します)。区切り文字を指定して空の文字列を分割すると、 [''] を返します。
>
> ```
> >>> '1,2,3'.split(',')
> ['1', '2', '3']
> >>> '1,2,3'.split(',', maxsplit=1)
> ['1', '2,3']
> >>> '1,2,,3,'.split(',')
> ['1', '2', '', '3', '']
> ```

---

似たような使い方と解説の記事を見つけたので追記：
まったく同じ例は無いですが。

[Python3で競技プログラミングする時に知っておきたいtips（入力編）](https://qiita.com/kyuna/items/8ee8916c2f4e36321a1c)